# operations about two lists to index a two dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, list

Code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array((1,1,1,1,2))
b = np.array((2,2,2,2,1))
g = np.zeros((3,3),np.int32)
g[a,b] += 1
```

At the end, this should give an array

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

i.e. g[1, 2] being incremented 4 times, and g[2, 1] being incremented once, but instead it gives

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

The reason that I don't want to use a loop is because I think the vectorization can accelerate the computation. I have two large sets `a` and `b`. But I'm not sure whether this operation can exploit performance from vectorization mechanism of Python. and I'm not sure I understand this operation neither. I don't know which key words I should use to search in google, so I put my question here.

If someone can help me understand it, that will be much better.

Comment: I don't understand. `g[a,b] = 4` seems to do what you want. What logic am I missing?

Comment: @roganjosh: Then `g[2, 1]` is also 4, when it should be 1. Each element of `g` should be incremented once for each time that element is selected by `a, b`; expecting `g[a, b] += 1` to do that is a common newbie pitfall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the [`at` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) of NumPy ufuncs is for:

```
numpy.add.at(g, (a, b), 1)
```

---

`g[a, b] += 1` would perform

```
temp = g[a, b]
temp += 1
g[a, b] = temp
```

creating a temporary array with 4 copies of `g[1, 2]`, incrementing each copy separately, and assigning each copy back over `g[1, 2]` (with the assignments stomping over each other).

`numpy.add.at(g, (a, b), 1)` instead performs the operation directly on the `g` array, so it increments `g[1, 2]` 4 times instead of incrementing 4 copies once each.

Comment: good explanation! and the vectorization does accelerate the computation. thank you.